# Automatically assign method arguments to instance variables

Tags: python, class, variables

Is there a way in Python to declare instance variables from the methods arguments without the need for boilerplate writing?

For example, is there a way for `self.foo`, `self.bar` and all other arguments to be automatically declared?

```py
def __init__(self, foo, bar, ..., last):
    self.foo = foo
    self.bar = bar
    ...
    self.last = last
```

Comment: Does https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html solve your problem?

Comment: I find `namedtuple` useful for things like this.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: You can use `dataclasses.dataclass` or `collections.namedtuple`, but you should be aware that these have specific use-cases

Comment: I'm actually discovering dataclasses right now. Didn't know it would be related to my question. I like the `namedtuple` option as it does restrict the available arguments compared to dict, or kwarg which could allow anything to be passed through. Will need to test these later

Answer (score 0):

There actually is, though I think it's a very ugly way

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)


Foo(name='foo', baz=123, bar=True, last=None)
```

As **Tim Roberts** suggested in the comments, using a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is a much better and cleaner way (you may also take a look at [`dataclasses.dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a keyword argument in `__init__`.  For example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

Then you can create a class using whatever keyword arguments you want:

```
>>> mc = MyClass(foo=123, bar=456, baz=789)
>>>
```

Those arguments are assigned as attributes of the class instance:

```
>>> mc.foo
123
>>> mc.bar
456
>>> mc.baz
789
>>>
```

You may want to add some checks if you do this, e.g. restrict them to some known set of names.  Otherwise an undesired name could override a method name for instance.

Or, you could save the keyword dictionary directly in the class instance, as a single attribute.  That would insulate the class from the names.  For example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.args = kwargs
```

You could then access them through `self.args`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

As @Tim Roberts suggested this is how it can be accomplished with a `namedtuple`.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

class Foo(namedtuple("Foo", ["param1", "param2"])):
    pass # Rest of code goes here

my_class = Foo(1, 2)
my_class.param1  # returns 1
```

You can even create default arguments

```py
namedtuple("Foo", ["param1", "param2"], defaults=[1, 2])
```

#### Solution 2

Alternatively, you can use `**kwargs` to set the instance variables (which doesn't use the collections library and is arguably easier) if you are fine with the user passing any random argument.

Here is an example

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__dict__.update(kwargs)

my_class = Foo(param1=1)
my_class.param1  # returns 1

# Doesn't force you to pass the correct parameters
random_param_class = Foo(a_made_up_parameter=2)
random_param_class.param1  # Results in an error
```

Bear in mind that none of this is standard and most often people just declare the instance variables from within `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, if you have a fixed sets of inputs, you can use this:

```
from inspect import getargvalues, stack

def arguments():
    args = getargvalues(stack()[1][0])[-1]
    del args['self']
    if 'kwargs' in args:
        args.update(args['kwargs'])
        del args['kwargs']
    return args

class myClass():
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, ..., last):
        # Auto update all arguments into object dictionary
        self.__dict__.update(arguments())
```

This should do it, if you don't specify *kwargs

```
object = myClass(1,2,3,'foo','random')
# all the right instances will be created
# object.foo =1
# object.bar = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how your method signature looks like (whether there are positional and/or keyword arguments pre-defined or not), you can always use `locals()` (prior to declaring other local variables):

```
def __init__(self, foo=3, bar='f', *args, **kwargs):
  for name, value in locals().items():
    if name != 'self': setattr(self, name, value)
```

This way, ***all*** arguments are copied to instance variables.